# how to save session using firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have implemented user registration in my application using

```
firebase.auth().SignInWithEmailAndPassword (email, password)
```

And I need that when a user comes to the site, his profile will be synchronized as logged in, even the page will be reloaded or closed and opened again

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: " ",
      password: " ",
      hasAccount: false,
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const db = firebase.database();
    console.log(db)
  }

  handleChange = ({ target: { value, id } }) => {
       this.setState({ [id] : value })
  }

  createAccount = () => {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    

        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword( email, password)
          .then(Response => {
            console.log(Response)
            this.setState({ hasAccount: true })
          })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
      
        const auth = firebase.app().auth();
        auth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many environments Firebase already persists the user's authentication credentials, and you don't need to explicitly enabled that with `auth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)`.

But to pick up the restored authentication state when the app is restarted/page reloaded, you need to use an `onAuthStateChanged` handler, as shown in the fist snippet in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    this.setState({ hasAccount: true })
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

You'll typically put this code in the constructor of your component, so that it starts monitoring authentication state right away.

Comment: Then I will not fully understand what needs to be inserted into this fragment?
judging by the documentation  `  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean there Dmitriy. Did you include an `onAuthStateChanged` listener in your code, and modify its body to your needs? What happened when you did that?

Comment: Following the example, I executed the following code.
The console displays everything ok.
but when you reboot again you need to enter the password and email.
that is, what I need does not work?
what could be my mistake?

Comment: ` firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          if (user) {
            console.log('It is Okey')
          } else {
            console.log('Wow what going on?')
          }
        });`

Comment: If you just `console.log` the authentication state, that won't make much of a difference. Inside the `onAuthStateChanged` you will need to update your UI to the correct state. So if `user` has a value, you should display the information of that user instead of the login screen.

Comment: But is there an example in the documentation of how to display the state of the user's input in this design?
Thank you so much for your answers!

Comment: I added a line from your code that I think should probably be in the auth state listener. But this is *your* application logic, so *you're* the most likely person to know what needs to go there. I "merely" answered the question in the title: how to persist and restore the user's authentication state.

Comment: everything worked fine, I just put the observer in the wrong place
I put it in the `createAccount` function , but I needed it in `componentDidMount ()`

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
      this.setState({ hasAccount: true })
    }
  });
```